# Did my android location manager fix come from a cell tower or wi-fi

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager

I have an android app that uses LocationManager to get geolocation fixes, using either fine (GPS) or coarse (network/wi-fi) location, and I need to know where any specific location fix came from.

I can use

> if (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.equals(location.getProvider())){...

to determine that the fix was from GPS
and

> if (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER.equals(location.getProvider())){...

to determine that it was from either a mobile network or from wi-fi, but I don't know which.

My problem is that the app is designed to be used on trains, and train wi-fi doesn't always give the right position (I once travelled from London to Paris on Eurostar, and throughout the journey the geolocation told me that we were at Paris Gare du Nord - even when the train was at London St Pancras!)

Does anyone know a way of telling LocationManager to ignore wi-fi and give me only locations from my mobile network or GPS? If that isn't possible, is there at least a way to tell whether a coarse location came from a mobile network of from wi-fi?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have stumbled across the answer to my own question when looking for something else. I found this statement:

> Applications cannot specify the exact location sources, such as GPS, that are used by the LocationClient. In fact, the system may have multiple location sources (providers) running and may fuse the results from several sources into a single Location object.

here:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest

Looks as if I can't do what I want. If anyone knows a way, please let me know.